# How long does it take to cook frozen peas in a slow cooker?

Tags: frozen, greens

I mostly use frozen peas for cooking. But sometimes they remain hard even if I cook them for a bit longer, but peas remain pretty hard and fibrous, not soft. What can be done to avoid their hardness. I also do not put them directly to cooker. I soak them for sometime but this trick is also not working. What can be the reasons?

Comment: How long are you cooking them? how are you cooking them? how much peas do you add? Are you talking about peas in a pod or just the peas - I never had just peas that were fibrous, even raw.

Comment: Which peas? Green peas? Were they frozen at home or store-bought frozen? If frozen at home, were they blanched before freezing? Why do you feel the need to soak them? If they're frozen, you can try thawing them first instead of soaking.

Answer (score 3):

Adding frozen stuff directly to a slow cooker drops the temperature of the whole pot, which takes some time to recover.

I don't often use peas in mine but I've never had a problem with them if I pour boiling water over them and wait a few minutes before draining them and stirring them in, when the rest of the dish is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Don't peas just get tougher the longer you cook them?
*This is something I've heard but never wanted to waste food testing.*

For the teensy sweet type you get from BirdsEye etc, all they need is to be warmed up - drop boiling water on them, or just throw them in right as you're about to serve.

The most I ever do for frozen peas is drop them in boiling water & bring it back to the boil.
Serve immediately.